# what is pg_replication_slot_advance() function in logical replication and how the values restart_lsn and confirmed_flush_lsn change after advancing?

Tags: postgresql, pg-logical

information provided about the function in PostgreSQL documentation.

pg_replication_slot_advance ( slot_name name, upto_lsn pg_lsn ) → record ( slot_name name, end_lsn pg_lsn )

Advances the current confirmed position of a replication slot named slot_name. The slot will not be moved backwards, and it will not be moved beyond the current insert location. Returns the name of the slot and the actual position that it was advanced to. The updated slot position information is written out at the next checkpoint if any advancing is done. So in the event of a crash, the slot may return to an earlier position.

Explain what exactly the above lines mentions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_15_3/src/backend/replication/slotfuncs.c#L451

For a logical replication slot, this function starts a logical decode and skips any changes before the specified LSN. `confirmed_flush` position of this slot will be set to the value returned by the function. `restart_lsn` will also be moved forward if possible.

For a physical replication slot, this function updates `restart_lsn`.

Comment: static XLogRecPtr pg_logical_replication_slot_advance(XLogRecPtr moveto) 

Does the return value of above function is always greater/lesser than ''moveto''...? –

Comment: Greater or equal.

Comment: In the definition that i provided from postgresql documentation what is "current confirmed position"....is it confirmed_flush_lsn in logical slot?...and restart_lsn in case of physical slot?

Comment: yes _(some padding for to short comment)_

Comment: how to find exactly the valid moveto_lsn we need to advance our slot??...also what type of change does moveto_lsn points to?........ like row_insert/createTable/updateTable etc?

valid moveto_lsn in sense after advancing,our slot should still continue  logical decoding with out any error.

Comment: First: why do you need to advance the slot?

Comment: im just curious..so im analysing how the function works..but i cannot understand how can i find the valid moveto_lsn point in wal records...im trying to mimic this function for lower versions...of postgres

Comment: Hi,can u tell some applications where this function is used?

Comment: I hope there aren't any. The function is listed in the "System Administration Functions" section of the documentation because it is not intended for regular use.